# Set language on Docusign e-mail

Tags: docusignapi

I want to send emails to different users in different countries by using the Docusign API.

For each signer the body and subject are changed by the "emailNotification"

```
EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification
{
      "emailSubject" : "SomeText",
      "emailBlurb" : "SomeText",
      "SupportedLanguage": "TwoLetterCountry"
}
```

When the user opens the document, all the items are in the correct language.
However, the mail that has been send to the user still contains items in english. For instance "(User) sent you a document to review and sign"  (The subject and body are what they are suppose to be).

Is the emailNotification suppose to change the country settings of just the document or can it also change the email language?

Comment: Excellent question. I have asked DocuSign engineering for assistance.

Comment: You're setting the EmailNotification field for ALL of the envelope's recipients? (Not just for the signers?)

Comment: The only recipients are the signers (no carbon copies or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the algorithm used to determine the language for emails to the signers is complicated.

There is some [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/release-notes/July-2017-Service-Pack-Notes.pdf) on the subject.

In addition:

- Are you using a custom branding file? If so then you need to supply the branding file in the multiple languages you want to support.

The DocuSign eSignature product looks at the following settings and inputs when determining language for emails:

- the set of languages available in a brand,
- the recipient’s user language (only used if the recipient has their own account on DocuSign. Many recipients or signers do not.)
- the language the recipient signed the given envelope with,
- the language selected by the sender for a given recipient (via the `SupportedLanguage` field),
- the sender’s user language, and
- the default language.

So if it isn't working, I'd check:

- If branding is being used, does your custom brand file include the target language you want? (Or to debug, try without a branding file.)
- Check to see if the recipient has an account on DocuSign. If they do, what language does that account use? Or test with a new signer that doesn't have an account on DocuSign.

Comment: Great! We did use a custom branding file (only at first to change the logo). Now I removed the custom brand and sent it again. Currently it gives the exact result I needed. At least I know now how to go from here. Thank you for time!