# Docusign - Set Recipient Language - emails received by the recipient are always in English

Tags: docusignapi

In the new Docusign API, there is support to set the language the recipient will be notified. It seems straight forward using "RecipientEmailNotification" class under Docusign SOAP API.

But for some reason the emails received by the recipient is always in English. Reviewed all the steps mentioned in this documentation: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/

Looked at below articles:

[Embedded DocuSign signing: using recipient's language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785088/embedded-docusign-signing-using-recipients-language/27028950#27028950)

[Set language on Docusign e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994404/set-language-on-docusign-e-mail)

-- Docusign class created from WSDL --

```
public class DocuSignAPI{
    public class RecipientEmailNotification {
    public String Subject;
    public String EmailBlurb;
    public String Language;
    private String[] Subject_type_info = new String[]{'Subject','http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] EmailBlurb_type_info = new String[]{'EmailBlurb','http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] Language_type_info = new String[]{'Language','http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'Subject','EmailBlurb','Language'};
}
}
```

-- Class to initiate e-signature --

```
//Set envelope
DocuSignAPI.Envelope envelope = new DocuSignAPI.Envelope();
envelope.Subject = 'test subject';
envelope.EmailBlurb = 'test blurb';
envelope.AccountId  = accountId; 

//Add recipient to envelope
DocuSignAPI.Recipient pdfRecipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
pdfRecipient.ID = i+1;
pdfRecipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
pdfRecipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
pdfRecipient.Email = 'test@google.com';
pdfRecipient.UserName = 'test user';
pdfRecipient.RequireIDLookup = false;      

//Set recipient language
DocuSignAPI.RecipientEmailNotification emailNotification = new DocuSignAPI.RecipientEmailNotification();
emailNotification.Subject = 'SomeText';
emailNotification.EmailBlurb = 'SomeText';
emailNotification.Language = 'zh_CN';    
pdfRecipient.EmailNotification = emailNotification;

//Call DocuSign API
DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus es = dsApiSend.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
```

The email to recipient "test@google.com" should be in zh_CN but it is received in English (EN).

Comment: Have you modified any resource file inside your brand?

Comment: Hi Amit, do you mean the class that got created from the Docusign WSDL? No, we have not updated that.

Comment: No, I wanted to know if you modified the resource file inside the [branding](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding)

Comment: Hi Amit, we have not modified branding file. But happy to check that out. Our Docusign knowledge is limited, we only interact via the API. Can you please point in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure this feature is enabled on your account (see support article - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-recipient-language) in order to use this feature. Please see if you can do this from the web application UI first to confirm you have this feature.